# How to compute cummin within groups with restricted lookahead?

Tags: python, pandas

**Old**

Given the following example:

```
group value
 5     1
10     2
 5     3
10     4
10     5
 7     6
 7     7
 7     8
 7     9
 5    10
```

I would like to compute `cummax`, however, I would like to have a lookahead of 2 before grouping. That is the result should be

```
group value
 5     3
10     4
 5     3
10     5
10     5
 7     8
 7     9
 7     9
 7     9
 5    10
```

How can I compute this with Pandas?

**New**

My current approach is as follows (based on Ezer K's suggestion). Do you have any suggestions to improve readability/performance?

```
def cum_func_lookahead(g, v, func1, func2, lookahead):
d = defaultdict(list)

result = [np.nan] * len(g)

def d_(g, v):
    d[g].append(v)
    if len(d[g]) > 1:
        d[g][-1] = func1(d[g][-2], d[g][-1])
    return d[g][-1]

for i in range(len(g)):
    lookahead_g = g[i:i+lookahead]
    lookahead_v = v[i:i+lookahead]

    mask = (lookahead_g == g[i])
    lookahead_v = lookahead_v[mask]

    max_v = func2(lookahead_v, axis=0)

    result[i] = d_(g[i], max_v)


result = np.asarray(result)
return result


result = np.asarray(result)
return result
```

The performance:

```
LENGTH = 100000
g = np.random.randint(low=0, high=LENGTH/2, size=LENGTH)
v = np.random.rand(LENGTH, 40)
%timeit r1 = cum_func_lookahead(g, v, np.maximum, np.max, 3)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.18 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to iterate through the df and update a new max dict if indeed the new max is bigger than the old max:

Create a dict where the keys are the groups and the values are initialized with zeroes:

```
max_dict = dict(zip(df.group.unique(),df.group.nunique()*[0]))
```

Go through the rows of the df (your original data frame), look ahead, update dict if necessary and append the current max to a list:

```
l = []
for t in df.iterrows():
    tmp_df = df.ix[t[0]:(t[0]+2)]
    tmp_df = tmp_df[tmp_df['group']==t[1]['group']]
    tmp_max =  max(tmp_df['value'].values)
    if tmp_max>max_dict[t[1]['group']]:
        max_dict[t[1]['group']] = tmp_max
    l.append( max_dict[t[1]['group']] )

df['com_max'] = l

    group   value   com_max
    0   5   1   3
    1   10  2   4
    2   5   3   3
    3   10  4   5
    4   10  5   5
    5   7   6   8
    6   7   7   9
    7   7   8   9
    8   7   9   9
    9   5   10  10
```

Comment: I reimplemented your approach in numpy (see question). Do you have any suggestions how to improve it further?

Answer (score 0):

This solution first groups on `group` and creates a custom function for `apply` which iteratively chooses at most 2 indexes ahead for each group and finds the max of that subset of that group and then reorders the frame back to its original order.

```
def max2(x):
    max_vals = [x.loc[idx:idx+2, 'value'].max() for idx in x.index]
    return pd.Series(max_vals, index=x.index, name='value')

df.groupby('group').apply(max2).reset_index('group').reindex(df.index)
```

Output

```
   group  value
0      5      3
1     10      4
2      5      3
3     10      5
4     10      5
5      7      8
6      7      9
7      7      9
8      7      9
9      5     10
```

### Built-in Pandas solution

Another solution relies on additional functionality of the `rolling` method. The `rolling` method allows the window size to be determined by date range. The default window is a constant number which doesn't work for this problem. But if you turn the index into a datetimelike index then you can take advantage of the `rolling` method and slice by dates.

Annoyingly, the `rolling` method does does not have a forward-looking option so you must reverse the DataFrame first.

First reverse and create a new index with as days.

```
df = df[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, 'D')
```

Which yields this:

```
        group  value
0 days      5     10
1 days      7      9
2 days      7      8
3 days      7      7
4 days      7      6
5 days     10      5
6 days     10      4
7 days      5      3
8 days     10      2
9 days      5      1
```

Then use Pandas built-in rolling method which yields the exact same DataFrame as above.

```
df.groupby('group')\
  .rolling('3D', min_periods=0)['value']\
  .max()\
  .reset_index(0)\
  .reindex(df.index)[::-1]\
  .reset_index(drop=True)
```